# What major non-hermetic virtue would be appropriate for an ex-Ex Misc who wants to be Flambeau?

Tags: optimization, ars-magica-5

One of my PCs is creating a character that has left her (probably mystery cult) in Ex Misc, and tried (and failed) to join House Flambeau as part of her backstory.

I cannot find a major non-hermetic virtue that I think would suit her character. Most supernatural virtues are silly XP-sinks that just replicate hermetic powers or are aligned with different realms.

Is there a major virtue (mysteries are... okay, if a bit eeeh) that would complement a character interested in Auram, Ignem, and Mentem, that is either a non-ability virtue (i.e. no XP sink) or is worth the XP investment?

She's also a new player to Ars Magica (in a group of 3 others who played a 3 year campaign with me), so I'd prefer not to introduce her to any of the major hedge magic traditions that have a *completely different* spellcasting system.

Bonus points for explosions.

Comment: Is this question still relevant to your group, Brian?

Comment: Yep. I never found a virtue that really makes me happy.

Answer (score 1):

The Mythic Blood virtue (Ars Magica 5th Ed. Corebook) is a good virtue for your purpose, but is listed as an hermetic one (but it eludes me why is listed as hermetic, to have mythic blood, for example Dragon's blood i think it's completely non related to hermetic training).

Also there's other virtues that fits for a Flambeau wannabe like Elemental Magic and Elemental Fire but they are from Hedge Magic revised edition (page 15 and 18) and I don't have it, at least Elemental Magic was XP sinks in previous editions.

All the above if you are thinking a flame wielding flambeau, not a "Perdo All" flambeau...